# Perl script skipping if conditions

Tags: html, perl, perl-module

Hi Im very new to perl and Im having an issue where part of my script is being skipped.

Im trying to validate a user. If the user enters admin and admin it displays a welcome screen, else it displays an error.

The script keeps skipping my if condition. Any Ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $object = new CGI;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
if ($object->param("submit")) {
    validate_form ();
} else {
    display_form ();
}

sub validate_form {
    my $user = $object->param("user");
    my $password = $object->param("password");
    my $user2 = "admin";
    my $password2 = "admin";
    my $wrong = "WRONG";
    if (my $user == my $user2 && $password == $password2) {
        print $password;
    } else {
        print $wrong;
    }
}

sub display_form {
    print <<END_HTML;

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Assignment 1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="/~int322_132sa13/cgi-bin/assn1/test2.pl" enctype="mu

    User Name: <input type="text" name="user"  />
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

    END_HTML
}
```

Comment: Did you really `use warnings`? You should get multiple error message explaining what went wrong where exactly. What do they say? (Hints: variables are getting redeclared, undef values are getting compared, string values are compared as numbers). Oh btw, printing a password seems like a moronic idea, I hope this isn't going to be “production code”.

Comment: If looking into your server logs for your errors is too much work, you could always `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);`, `use warnings FATAL` could help too.

Comment: @amon Im assuming I should be using eq instead of ==. And this Purely test environment. The error I get is "Can't locate object method "new" via package "CGI" at test2.pl line 6." Again new to perl not sure how to fix that

Comment: Does `display_form` work? I'm quite sure `END_HTML` at the end shouldn't be indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove "my" before $user in your if condition

```
if (my $user == my $user2 && $password == $password2) {
```

This would create another scalar *user*.

You also want to use a string equality using the "eq" operator.

So change above to:

```
if ($user eq $user2 && $password eq $password2) {
```

Comment: Also need to use `eq` for string comparisons, not `==`.